# How to get list from set of coordinates?

Tags: python, python-3.7

How to flatten the coordinates?

```
For input  :[(1,2),(5,6),(7,8)]
```

expecting the output as [1,2,5,6,7,8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
mylist = [(1,2),(5,6),(7,8)]
newlist = []
for x in mylist:
  newlist += x
 
print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

from the itertools doc page

```
from itertools import chain
def flatten(listOfLists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)
```